# Solving a modular equation with a large modulus

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am having trouble solving this equation:

$17^n\equiv 1 \mod 640826899755722841329632946651705039010285107743541637238400825304943424424715705661705191669759$

for the smallest integer $n > 0$

I tried Wolfram|Alpha, but it did not help me. I realize that it would be easy to solve this equation if we knew the prime factors of the modulus. Could you help me to find a solution for this equation?

Comment: If we can completely factorize the modulus,then the problem will be solved. Does anyone know the factors of that modulus. Using wolframalpha I just found 2 prime factors of that modulus.

Comment: It is easy to solve this equation,all we need just the prime factors of the modulus.

Answer (score 1):

This is what `MultiplicativeOrder[]` should be used for. As my computer is a bit on the weak side, I'll use a smaller example:

```
MultiplicativeOrder[17, 640826899755722841]
  476643402271080
```

Check:

```
PowerMod[17, %, 640826899755722841]
   1
```